# command design pattern and projectreactor.io reactive framework with spring webflux

Tags: design-patterns, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am having a springboot webflux application using reactive framework and the requirement is to use command design pattern. However, as per my understanding with reactive framework and `subscribe` approach, I am assuming it might be difficult or not worth using command design pattern with reactive. I developed a lot of non reactive springboot apps with command design pattern, but could not see it fit for webflux reactive.

Can I get some examples for webflux reactive with command design pattern

Comment: It's not really clear what prevents you from using a Command Design Pattern with Reactor